# Bifundamental representations

Tags: terminology, group-theory, group-representations

Can someone give me explicit examples (in matrix form) of [bifundamental representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifundamental_representation)? Illustrative would be for instance:

a) SU(3) x SU(2)

b) SO(4) x U(1)

c) E6 x U(1)

but other you may have ready would also work. A reference would also be great.

Answer (score 1):

I will talk about $SU(3) \times SU(2)$.

First, a matrix $T_3 \in SU(3)$ acts in the fundamental representation on $\mathbb C^3$ in the following way: A vector $\vec v \in \mathbb C^3$ with components $v_i$ is mapped to $v'_i = (T_3)_{ij} v_j$. Similarly, a $T_2 \in SU(2)$ acts on $\vec w \in \mathbb C^2$ as $w'k = (T_2)_{kl} w_l$.

The bifundamental representation of $SU(3) \times SU(2)$ acts on $\mathbb C^6$, the only difficulty is the choice of basis. It is easiest to describe the action if we label the components of $\vec v \in \mathbb C^6$ as $v_{ik}$ for $i \in \{1,2,3\}$ and $k \in \{1,2\}$.
Then the element $(T_3, T_2) \in SU(3) \times SU(2)$ acts as
$$ v'_{ik} = (T_3)_{ij} (T_2)_{kl} v_{jl} \;. $$

If you really want to write this in matrix form, you first have to fix some order of the basis of $\mathbb C^6$. For example, we could write the components in as a vector
$$ (v_{11}, v_{12}, v_{21}, v_{22}, v_{31}, v_{32})^T \;. $$
After some thinking, it turns out that the group action can then be written as the following matrix:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
 (T_3)_{11} (T_2)_{11} & (T_3)_{11} (T_2)_{12} & (T_3)_{12} (T_2)_{11} & \cdots & (T_3)_{13} (T_2)_{12} \\
 (T_3)_{11} (T_2)_{21} & (T_3)_{11} (T_2)_{22} & \ddots && \vdots \\
 \vdots &&&& \vdots \\
 (T_3)_{31} (T_2)_{21} & \cdots &&& (T_3)_{33} (T_2)_{22}
\end{pmatrix} \;. $$

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer! Too bad that this question has been put on hold. It's not a homework problem. I admire the people who understand things immediately deductively from an abstract concept, but I often need to see examples worked out explicitly, so I asked for some. (Any others would also have been fine.) Your answer shows that it probably does not make sense to write things in matrix form (especially for E6) but having seen it was illuminating. Thanks again.